# Can JSPM load scripts from external URL's?

Tags: systemjs, jspm

I import jQuery with JSPM - in development mode this is done async.

I have an external script, which would be located here for example: https://www.example.com/script-that-requires-jquery.js

The external script requires jQuery, and uses the document ready event.
The problem is, that script won't work because jQuery is loaded async via JSPM.

Can JSPM load scripts from external URL's?

If not, I'll have to reference jQuery normally, in my html source without jspm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a recommended approach because it is not described in the [docs](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/07cd319bd4ffb46d68af47c681cfd0826421c2a7/docs/installing-packages.md).
But you can load an import via external url by modifying its mapping in the jspm config file.
So you might install jQuery via

```
jspm install jquery
```

and then changing the map entry in the jspm-config.js to something like

```
map: {
    ...
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js",
    ...
},
```

Again, this might not be the way jspm in intended to be used.